Position outputting lists which seemingly have the wrong dimension for the input array
I am writing some straightforward code to find the structure constants of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ and experienced a weird result when using the position function to ask which positions had specific values. Here is my code
SU3BASIS = {{{0, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, -(I/2), 0}, {I/2, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{1/2, 0, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
   1/2}, {0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, -(I/2)}, {0, 0, 0}, {I/2, 0,
    0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 1/2, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, -(I/2)}, {0, I/2, 0}}, {{1/(2 Sqrt[3]), 0, 0}, {0, 1/(
   2 Sqrt[3]), 0}, {0, 0, -(1/Sqrt[3])}}};
comm = Table[
   SU3BASIS[[i]] . SU3BASIS[[j]] - SU3BASIS[[j]] . SU3BASIS[[i]], {i, 1, 
    8}, {j, 1, 8}];
struct = Table[-2*I*Tr[comm[[i, j]] . SU3BASIS[[k]]], {i, 1, 8}, {j, 1, 
    8}, {k, 1, 8}];

pos1 = Position[struct, _?(# == -Sqrt[3]/2 &)]


{{4, 8, 5}, {5, 4, 8}, {6, 8, 7}, {7, 6, 8}, {8, 5, 4}, {8, 7, 6}}

pos2 = Position[struct, 1/2]


{{1, 4, 7}, {1, 6, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 5, 7}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 7, 6}, {4,
5,    3}, {4, 5, 8, 1}, {4, 5, 8, 2, 2}, {4, 6, 2}, {4, 7, 1}, {4, 8,
5, 2,    2}, {5, 1, 6}, {5, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 8, 2, 2}, {5, 7, 2}, {5, 8,
4, 1}, {5, 8,    4, 2, 2}, {6, 2, 4}, {6, 3, 7}, {6, 5, 1}, {6, 7, 8,
1}, {6, 7, 8, 2,    2}, {6, 8, 7, 2, 2}, {7, 1, 4}, {7, 2, 5}, {7, 6,
3}, {7, 6, 8, 2, 2}, {7,    8, 6, 1}, {7, 8, 6, 2, 2}, {8, 4, 5, 1},
{8, 4, 5, 2, 2}, {8, 5, 4, 2,    2}, {8, 6, 7, 1}, {8, 6, 7, 2, 2},
{8, 7, 6, 2, 2}}

Dimensions[struct]


{8, 8, 8}

As you can see, some of the outputs of pos2 have 5 indices, but I constructed struct to be an 8x8x8 table, so it should only have 3 indices. For example, one output is $\{4,8,5,2,2\}$. In the above code, Extract[{4,8,5,2,2}] is 1/2, but Extract[{4,8,5}] is -Sqrt[3]/2.
Can someone explain why this is happening or what this means? I would like to exclude these results which have outputs of a weird shape.

You have Sqrt[3]/2 entries in struct. The FullForm shows that it has two Rational entries that match.
FullForm[Sqrt[3]/2]


Times[Rational[1,2],Power[3,Rational[1,2]]]

To avoid it, use the levelspec argument and restrict Position to the third level:
pos2 = Position[struct, 1/2, 3]


{{1, 4, 7}, {1, 6, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 5, 7}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 7, 6}, {4,
5, 3}, {4, 6, 2}, {4, 7, 1}, {5, 1, 6}, {5, 3, 4}, {5, 7, 2}, {6,
2, 4}, {6, 3, 7}, {6, 5, 1}, {7, 1, 4}, {7, 2, 5}, {7, 6, 3}}


Thanks for the accept. @tadpolio
